# Is there a momentary switch that cuts the signal only the very instant it is pressed?

Tags: switches, audio, diy, guitar-pedal

I am trying to build a guitar kill switch that would behave like a typical momentary switch, but with a twist: I would like the audio signal to be interrupted only the very moment I press the button (for about 80ms). Meaning that the signal would pass again after this brief instant whether I keep my finger on the button or not.
Releasing the button would not achieve any new action, and the button mechanism would have to be spring-loaded to reset itself at its neutral position so it can be engaged again very shortly after.

Is there a button that performs like this out of the box, or would I need some circuit board to achieve what I described?

Comment: Do you have a ballpark for the interruption time?  I can guess that 1 us might be too small, and 10 s might be too long, but beyond that it's not clear what you need.  Not sure if there's anything off-the-shelf, but it wouldn't be difficult with a small amount of additional circuitry.

Comment: Something around 80ms would be appropriate I think. It would allow for fast repetitions with clear separation between two presses.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a latching break-before-make SPDT switch and just solder both of its alternates together, it should behave in the manner you describe.  How useful that would be is a different question...

Comment: A friend of mine is putting incredible efforts learning guitar despite having some motor coordination issues. I would like to surprise him with a guitar pickguard loaded with a kill-switch he would be able to use as precisely as possible.
He tried on my guitar but the  "pressing the button only for the duration I want" part is hard for him, and his finger stays too long on the button.

Comment: In that case it might be smarter to use a lever-action SPDT switch than a latching push-button switch: it's probably easier to throw a switch back and forth than press a button twice in the same time.  Also the mechanics will likely last longer.  And you could try a three-position switch in order to have the possibility for control over the dead-time by passing over the middle position faster or slower.